# Running command with make gives different result from running it directly in shell

Tags: bash, docker, makefile

I have a **Makefile** that looks like this:

```
build-docker:
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_rsa -t my-app .
```

If I run `make build-docker` I get the following error:

```
$ make build-docker
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_rsa -t my-app .
could not parse ssh: [default=~/.ssh/id_rsa]: stat ~/.ssh/id_rsa: no such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:12: build-docker] Error 1
```

However, if I run the command directly in the shell it runs just fine:

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_rsa -t my-app .
[+] Building 65.5s (20/20) FINISHED
```

Why is this and how do I solve it?

Comment: You are not running the same command. Your test one uses sudo hence `~` resolves to an other user home directory (i.e. `/root`). Your error message is quite clear => `/<your>/<home>/.ssh/id_rsa` does not exist.

Comment: Oh, I was experimenting a bit with sudo, forgot to remove it from the command. However, even with sudo excluded from both the Makefile and my direct command, I get this unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the same command, but in different shells.  Your interactive shell is probably `bash`.  But the shell make uses is `/bin/sh` which is a POSIX standard shell (often).

The special handling of `~` in an argument is a shell feature: it's not embedded in programs like docker or ssh.  And, it's not defined in POSIX; it's an additional feature that some shells, like `bash`.

On my system:

```
bash$ echo foo=~
foo=/home/me

bash$ /bin/sh

$ echo foo=~
foo=~
```

To be portable you should use the full pathname or `$HOME` instead (remember that in a make recipe you have to double the `$` to escape it from make: `$$HOME`).

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you!